# How do you account for suppressed values in a time series regression?

Tags: regression, time-series, censoring

I'm analysing time series data of monthly traffic fatalities in several US states, but have come upon a problem with suppressed values. The data come from CDC WONDER, and cells with any value less than 10 are automatically suppressed. As many of the states are small, they often include suppressed values.

To conduct my regression, I've assigned them as NA (essentially, treated as missing) but this clearly isn't the best approach. What's the best way to account for suppressed values in a time series regression?

I'm using R with gls() from the nlme package, if that helps frame the question.

Answer (score 1):

After speaking with @IrishStat, the answer seems to be that there is no way to correct for this. We tried predicting values using various tests, but many were well above the maximum dictated by suppression/left censoring criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Missing vales can be entered as a zeroes and intervention detection procedures http://docplayer.net/12080848-Outliers-level-shifts-and-variance-changes-in-time-series.html will detect these "anomalies" and estimate what the replacement value should be. This approach fails when the zeroes dominate.

Comment: This is not a missing-values situation: the data have been *censored*, but they are present.  Replacing them with zeros will definitely bias the analysis, potentially greatly.

Comment: the idea is that by detecting the zeroes whether they are real zeroes or just missing values replacing them with adjusted values one can go forward .The caveat is that if the zeroes exist in large amounts it is not possible to determine an adjustment. Consider 1,9,1,9,1,9,1,9,0,9 where the 0 represents a missing value. The replacement value should/could be a 1 leading to a clearer picture of the underlying signal

Comment: On the contrary, there are many methods to account for such censoring, depending on model assumptions.  Representing these left-censored values purely as missing is going to be biased.  It's well established that replacing left-censored values by constants is one of the poorest possible methods for many purposes.  See Dennis Helsel, *Nondetects and Data Analysis*.

Comment: 1,9,1,9,1,9,1,9,1,0,1,9,1,9,1,9  is not left-censored and the final estimated replacement for the unusual "0" would be a "9'

Comment: Thanks for the lively discussion. In this case, replacing the unusual "0" with a "9" suggests the approach may not be the one I'm looking for. Because my values are suppressed, they are going to be lower than any value in the time series. So if I had a series: c(22, 15, 19, NA["Suppressed"], 11), my guess is that with this method, "0" substitution would then predict a value somewhere between 11 and 22, when it should really be below 10. Do correct me if I'm wrong, though.

Comment: Not necessarily ... The replacement value is the predicted value for that period .....so..if the series is  20,19,18,17,16,o.... the predicted value might be 15 which is lower than the minimum observed value ...My question to you is why you know that the value should be 10 . If you wish you can SKYPE me and perhaps we can work this out as special override files exist. You could then report your findings to the list as our purpose here is to provide transparent improvements to our common skills.

Comment: Thanks. That would be useful. I'll send you an email to set it up, along with a copy of the data files.

Comment: Tyler, your guess is correct.  The worse problem is that if such a replacement rule were used to estimate a model, then it would impute biased replacement values.  Thus I am doubtful that any variant of the approach indicated here by IrishStat will produce unbiased results.

Comment: If the replacement value is the expected value based upon values prior to the missing value how can it be biased if care has been taken to separate signal and noise ?

Comment: Tyler , I have not received your email as of yet ...

Comment: Apologies, new father. Sending now.